# Creating HTML Templates with jQuery

Tags: jquery, email, templates, content-management-system, html-email

I'm looking to simplify the process of creating html emails, making it simple to drag and drop different elements to compile the final product.

I've created a series of html content blocks (1 column story, 2 column story, ad block etc), and would like to create something that will allow the user to:

1. Drag html content block elements to the stage as needed, and sort these at any point
2. Edit the text and image areas in each content block
3. Allow me to export the final compiled html - ready for a 3rd party email management app

I've taken a look at jQuery sortable & draggable, but know these are only a small part of the picture.  I was wondering if anyone had created something similar, or would be able to point me in the right direction in order to accomplish this?

Comment: You want an editor for that??

Comment: You would too if you've seen the length and complexity of the emails this company sends (which is another issue in and of itself)

Comment: I would say this isn't possible. Given the complexity and countless nuances of all the different email clients it would be extremely difficult

Comment: Surely if the templates are tested (litmus) and the modules are in self-contained tables, this should be a piece of cake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Jquery Templates, it offers you more flexibility [Jquery Template](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/)

from Jquery Examples.

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">  //this is template 
    <li><b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})</li>
</script>

<ul id="movieList"></ul>

<script>
var movies = [  // data for the template 
    { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
    { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
    { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
];

/* Render the template with the movies data and insert
   the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element */

$( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies )  
    .appendTo( "#movieList" );
</script>
```

and if you want more features, you can try HandleBar.JS [HandleBar JS](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

1. [Basic HandleBarjs expressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll check it out.  Should I be concerned they posted this warning? "The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta. It is no longer being actively developed or maintained."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, I've built exactly this tool before now.

Some gotchas:

- You will need a bit of server-side code as well, because whichever browser the end user is using will change the code slightly. I used some post-processing to clean up unnecessary / harmful code after.
- Avoid WYSIWYG editors, because you'll spend lots of time removing their junk while trying to keep the style the user was trying to have. Instead, use the `contenteditable` attribute, and your own simple styling options for bold, italic, and anything else you want to offer.
- Be aware of all the things you *could* do in a web browser (with CSS3) that you can't do in email. First render-test the templates in email clients, then turn them into your modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Render the template with the movies data and insert
   the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element */

$( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies ).appendTo( "#movieList" );
```